# Vectorization of summation of multipication of a 1D vector and a 3D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

`alpha` is a `M×1` vector, and `R` is a large array of size `n×n×M`. In my case, `n` and `M` are about 3000. How can I vectorize the following summation in MATLAB?

```
alpha(1)*R(:,:,1) + alpha(2)*R(:,:,2) + ... + alpha(M)*R(:,:,M)
```

One way I thought of was to make alpha the same size and do an element-wise operation and finally do a summation in the 3rd dimension

```
sum(reshape(kron(alpha, ones(n*n,1)), [n,n,M]).*R,3)
```

Could someone kindly let me know if there is a better and efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use singleton expansion, either with [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@times, R, reshape(alpha, 1, 1, [])), 3);
```

or [implicit](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
result = sum(R.*reshape(alpha, 1, 1, []), 3);
```

Alternatively, you can use matrix multiplication:

```
result = reshape(reshape(R, [], size(R,3))*alpha, size(R,1), size(R,2));
```